# Yet another fan control problem

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, fan, sensors

I'm using a 32-bit Linux Mint Rosa 17.3 with MATE DE (for the record, the same issue exists on a 64-bit flavor as well, and I have had this issue with every ubuntu-based distro). It is installed on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Laptop with 2GB RAM. All updates are installed.

The problem is, there is no fan control, either actively or passively. That is, I have no way of controlling the fan speed, and the system doesn't control it either. It's always running at a constant, high speed. There are no overheating problems (temperature monitors are working and report temps at ~58-60C). But the noise is bothering me.

What I have done:

1) `lm-sensors` is installed.

2) I have run `sudo sensors-detect`, without anything happening (i.e. it doesn't detect any fans, I only get this:

```
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
```

Here's the output of `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1: +50.8°C (crit = +109.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0: +48.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Here's the output of `inxi -Fxz`

```
System: Host: chris-AMILO-mint Kernel: 3.19.0-32-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 4.8.2)
Desktop: MATE 1.12.0 (Gtk 3.10.8~8+qiana) Distro: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Machine: System: FUJITSU SIEMENS product: AMILO Li1705 v: 20
Mobo: FUJITSU SIEMENS model: AMILO Li1705 v: 0.4
Bios: FUJITSU SIEMENS v: 1.0C-2308-8A20 date: 02/15/2007
CPU: Single core Intel Celeron M 520 (-UP-) cache: 1024 KB
flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3) bmips: 3191 speed: 1595 MHz (max)
Graphics: Card: VIA CN896/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC] bus-ID: 01:00.0
Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 drivers: openchrome (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1280x800@60.0hz
GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio: Card VIA VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 04:01.0
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.19.0-32-generic
Network: Card-1: VIA VT6102/VT6103 [Rhine-II] driver: via-rhine port: 4800 bus-ID: 00:12.0
IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg]
driver: ath5k bus-ID: 05:01.0
IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives: HDD Total Size: 160.0GB (8.3% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD1600BEVS size: 160.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 15G used: 7.7G (57%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
ID-2: swap-1 size: 5.24GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 59.8C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info: Processes: 133 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 457.1/1758.2MB Init: Upstart runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4
Client: Shell (bash 4.3.111) inxi: 2.2.28
```

What's going on here?

For the record, the laptop fans worked fine (i.e. they are detected and are controllable) when using Windows Vista (also installed)

Comment: I have the same problem on a desktop with a Fujitsu motherboard. Same output from `sensors-detect` and `sensors`, and `inxi` also says Fan Speeds: N/A. I don't know anything specific about Fujitsu mobos/support (yet), but at first glance it appears that linux or lm-sensors don't include drivers to read the Fujitsu fan controls. If this is correct, the question remains if there are any compatible drivers out there somewhere.